# can I get a list all nose attributes?

Tags: python, attributes, nose

I need 2 things here.

1. I want to be able to add attributes at will without needing to add `!attr` for each to my nosetests call (which I've hooked up to a mapping in Vim). I'm thinking something like `nosetests -a'NONE'`, but I can't find an option like this.
2. I also want to be able to discover which attributes I've added, so I can work up a little list/toggle mechanism in Vim for easily toggling tests on and off.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for?

```
from nose.plugins.attrib import attr
...
@attr(id='VD-333', type=('Functional', 'Negative'))
def test_invalid_where_with_field_alone(self):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
...
(Pdb++) self._testMethodName
'test_invalid_where_with_field_alone'
(Pdb++) y=getattr(self, self._testMethodName)
(Pdb++) y.id
'VD-333'
```